# Android Gradle: depends on libraries but is not a library itself

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm working on my gradle build for an android product to get product flavors working.

I have following project structure:

```
at.mkw.inlocs.android - Library Project
at.mkw.inlocs.android.lib - Library Project - depends on at.mkw.inlocs.android
at.mkw.inlocs.android.login - App Project - depends on at.mkw.inlocs.android
at.mkw.inlocs.android.core - App Project - depends on at.mkw.inlocs.android.lib
at.mkw.inlocs.android.breeding - App Project - depends on at.mkw.inlocs.android.lib
at.mkw.inlocs.android.localization - App Project - depends on at.mkw.inlocs.android.lib
at.mkw.inlocs.android.health - App Project - depends on at.mkw.inlocs.android.lib
```

Since adding product flavors to all app and library projects, I am getting an exception when building.

> [image]

I am using the newest gradle artifact (com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9+) and android build tools 19.0.3

Another problem is, that Android Studio doesn't show the at.mkw.inlocs.android.lib module in project view.

[image]

After switching to packages view, the module is visible, but has no content.

[image]

I have pasted the build.gradle files:

[root build script](http://pastebin.com/sWhMZRce)

[at.mkw.inlocs.android](http://pastebin.com/P5UmCMLy)

[at.mkw.inlocs.android.lib](http://pastebin.com/FibcHCqK)

[at.mkw.inlocs.android.login](http://pastebin.com/4v46L6gv)

[at.mkw.inlocs.android.core](http://pastebin.com/3ciU4X3p)

[at.mkw.inlocs.android.localization](http://pastebin.com/JCtRVDxk)

[at.mkw.inlocs.android.health](http://pastebin.com/ETrF4Rjv)

[at.mkw.inlocs.android.breeding](http://pastebin.com/GbKHZhje)

Comment: Quite a few, externally hosted files there. Might be better to paste relevant snippets onto this site; this question will be useless to future users when the links break, and there's a lot to wade through there.

Comment: @Poldie: i think the relevant snippets are to big to post it here.

Comment: if I remove the "configuration" tag from for example pigCompile project(path: ':at.mkw.inlocs.android.lib', configuration: 'pigRelease'), the build runs without any exception!

Comment: If the relevant snippets are too big to post, that means you'll need to reduce your question down to its essentials. If you just post your entire project, you won't get many people who will sift through the entire thing.

Comment: I think the problem is that in at.mkw.inlocs.android.lib you are defining flavors but you do not enable publishing of flavors, so it tries to publish the default variant which doesn't exist anymore due to the flavors. Please read: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-Publication

Comment: @Xavier Ducrohet `publishNonDefault true` fixed the problem. Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the build.gradle `at.mkw.inlocs.android`, you are using flavors in a library project.

While this is fine, current flavor support in library project is not final and by default the variants are not published (for consumption by other projects) due to some limitations.

To enable it you'll need to do

```
android {
    publishNonDefault true
}
```

reference: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-Publication